# Tags are still ALL CAPS on our weekly newsletter

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Tags are still ALL CAPS on our weekly newsletter:

[image]

Comment: I have informed our newsletter dev about this. It should be changed in the next email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags in the [Skeptics newsletter](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=skeptics.stackexchange.com) are lower-case now.